# What is a simple way to schedule a single event to happen at some time in the future?

Tags: command-line, scheduling

There are often times that I want my computer to do a single task, but not right now.  For example, I could have it notify me in 30 minutes that it is time to leave work.  Or maybe I want it to run a complicated test 2 hours from now when I'm sure most everyone else will be gone from the office.

I know I could create a cron job to run at a specific time of day, but that seems like a lot of work when all I want is something simple like "Run this script in 10 minutes", besides I'd have to figure out what time it will actually be X minutes/hours/days from now, and then delete the cron job once it finished.

Of course I could just write this script and run it in the background:

```
sleep X
do_task
```

But that just seems so clunky: I either need a new script for each task, or I need to write and maintain a script generic enough to do what I want, not to mention I have to figure out how many seconds are in the minutes, hours, or days I want.

Is there not an already established solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm guessing you've not run across [at](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Unix%29) yet?

Comment: this might seem very basic...but doesn't your system have any kind of calendar/todo list thing, with warnings?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I use a simple script with `at`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# email reminder notes using at(1)...

read -p "Time of message? [HH:MM] " time
read -p "Date of message? [dd.mm.yy] " date
read -p "Message body? " message

at "$time" "$date" <<EOF
echo "$message" | mailx -s "REMINDER" me@gmail.com
EOF
```

You could just as easily pipe the `$message` to `notify-send` or `dzen` if you wanted a desktop notification instead of an email.

Comment: Can also use relative time (`+ 2 days`) and different formats (`YYYY-MM-DD`).  Consult the manpage for more details.

Comment: Yes: us antipodeans prefer DD-MM-YY :)

Comment: I usually us at for quickie one off scripts. My favorite lazy way to schedule an at job is "now +5 minutes" which could also be hours or days.

Comment: +1 for script and for mentioning dzen and notify-send which I had not heard of.

Comment: The dzen redirection isn't working for me.  http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38362/4143

Answer (score 6):

The generic way to use [**`at`**](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?at) is

Write a script that does what you want to do. Use the full path for all external commands, log output to a proper log-file or mail it.

Test the script.

Activate it with `at -f YOURSCRIPT -t MMDDhhmm`

Answer (score 1):

In 2023 you would probably want to accomplish this with `systemd` instead of `at` since many distributions now disable `atd` by default.

You could use systemctl as follows:

```bash
systemd-run --user --on-calendar=<iso time> <command> [arguments...]
```

For instance

```bash
systemd-run --user --on-calendar="2023-11-03 07:00" /usr/bin/aplay /home/user/chime.wav
```

This creates a transient timer that would be deleted after the execution of the command. If instead the argument of --on-calendar contains asterisks, e.g.
--on-calendar="*-*-* 07:00", this command will be executed daily.

To get a list of all configured timers use

```
systemctl --user list-timers
```