# Why doesn't dzen2 work when invoked via at?

Tags: shell, x11, at

[dzen2](https://sites.google.com/site/gotmor/dzen) is a notification utility of sorts.  This command will make a notification that says "Hi" appear on the screen:

```
echo Hi | dzen2 -p
```

Debian's [at](http://packages.debian.org/stable/at) is a utility that schedules events to occur in the future.  This command will make the file "foo" appear in your user directory after 1 minute:

```
echo "touch ~/foo" | at now + 1 minute
```

So why is it that this command doesn't cause a `dzen2` notification to appear after 1 minute?

```
echo "echo Hi | dzen2 -p" | at now + 1 minute
```

I have been investigating for hours and cannot seem to find a reason why this doesn't work!  I have a hunch that it has to do with the shell that is invoked by at, but I just don't understand why it fails.  As a counterpoint example, this command works just fine:

```
echo "notify-send Hi" | at now + 1 minute
```

Comment: may have something to do with the $DISPLAY variable, but i don't know the details of `at`. someone else should chim in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program that constitutes the `at` job is a child of the `atd` (at [daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29)) process, not of the shell where you run `at`. So it does not inherit the current shell's environment. The `at` system arranges to copy the environment (and the working directory and a few more obscure thing), but it omits a few variables.

In particular, the `DISPLAY` variable is not copied to the at job. This variable tells all X programs which display to connect to. Without an X display, dzen2 doesn't know where to pop up a notification. At removes `DISPLAY` because it's usually used for batch jobs, which do not produce any terminal or graphical output.

`notify-send` works because it doesn't connect to the X server: it uses [D-bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus) to connect to a daemon that is attached to your X session.

You can make dzen2 work by explicitly copying the `DISPLAY` variable:

```
echo "export DISPLAY=$DISPLAY;" 'echo hello | dzen2 -p' | at now + 42 minutes
```

It's likely that dzen2 produces an error message (the standard message is `Can't open display:`). Any output or error message produced by the at job is sent by local mail (exactly like for cron jobs). Check your local mail.

Comment: Gilles to the rescue.  It is no wonder you have 87k reputation!  I know you have saved me on more than a few of my own questions.  Thumbs up to you, man, and thanks again.