# Why does this 'at' command not print to the standard output?

Tags: output, at

I am a relative Linux novice.  I am trying to learn how to use `at` so that I can schedule tasks to begin at a later time, without using `sleep`.  I have been looking at [this previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37793/what-is-a-simple-way-to-schedule-a-single-event-to-happen-at-some-time-in-the-fu) for help.

My question is, in the following sample bash script that I have created, why is **"Running"** never -- as far as I can tell -- printed to the standard output (i.e., my bash console)?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Started"

at now + 1 minutes <<EOF
echo "Running"
EOF

echo "Finished"
```

The only output I see is, for example:

> ```
> Started
> warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
> job 3 at Fri Jul 12 17:31:00 2013
> Finished
> ```

Is the answer to my question found in the warning?  If so, how does `/bin/sh` differ from the standard output?

Comment: try this: `sleep 3m; echo Running`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because `at` does not execute commands in the context of your logged in user session. The idea is that you can schedule a command to run at an arbitrary time, then log out and the system will take care of running the command at the specified time.

Note that the manual page for `at(1)` specifically says (my emphasis):

> **The user will be mailed** standard error  and  standard output from his commands, if any.  Mail will be sent using the command /usr/sbin/sendmail.

So you should be checking your local mail spool or, failing that, the local system mail logs. /var/spool/mail/$USER is probably a good place to start.

Also note that the "Started" and "Finished" originate from the outer script and in and of themselves have nothing to do with `at` at all. You could take out them or the `at` invocation and you'll get essentially the same result.

Answer (score 9):

I'm running Debian 8.1 (jessie)
You can have the the 'at' output go to a terminal by using tty.

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/1

$ at now + 1 min
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> echo 'ZZZZZ' > /dev/pts/1
at> <EOT>
```

One minute later, and 'ZZZZZ' will show up in your terminal...

Answer (score 8):

As @MichaelKjörling has explained it any output that's produced by your `at` job will be captured and sent to you via email. If you don't have a running [MTA - Mail Transfer Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) on your box then the email may be in limbo and you'll not know that `at` is even attempting to do this.

A MTA, is a program such as `sendmail` or `postfix` that can "deliver" email to an appropriate destination. In this case it's going to deliver it to a mail queue (a file under the directory `/var/spool/mail`) on your local system. Each user on the system can have a queue in this directory.

On my Fedora system if I start up `sendmail` then local mail delivery can occur. I typically have it off though.

```
$ sudo service start sendmail
```

Now we can see that my mail queue for my user account `saml` is empty:

```
$ ll /var/spool/mail/|grep saml
-rw-rw----. 1 saml mail       0 Jul 12 19:33 saml
```

So now we run the `at` job:

```
$ at now + 1 minutes <<EOF
echo "Running"
EOF
job 96 at Fri Jul 12 19:38:00 2013
```

We can see that the job is waiting to run with `atq`:

```
$ atq
96  Fri Jul 12 19:38:00 2013 a saml
```

Running it again after a couple of minutes we can see that the `at` job is complete:

```
$ atq
$
```

Incidentally, with my MTA running I now get this message in my terminal:

> You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/saml

So let's check:

```
$ ll /var/spool/mail/|grep saml
-rw-rw----. 1 saml mail     651 Jul 12 19:38 saml
```

Yup we've got mail, so let's check it out using `mutt`:

```
$ mutt -f /var/spool/mail/saml
```

We have this in our mail queue's "inbox":

[image: ss of mutt's inbox]

Let's check out this email:

[image: ss of mutt's msg]

And it worked.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - mutt rulz 8-)

Answer (score 2):

The above answers are the standard/"right" way to do it.

Another approach that's simpler from a more "end user" point of view is to have any scheduled or background task write its output to a "log" file. The file can be anywhere on your system, but if the task is running as root (from `cron`, etc.), then somewhere under `/var/log` is a good place to put it.

I created the `/var/log/maint` directory and made it readable by everybody and I have a readable file under that called "backup" where I log the output from my backup scripts.

I made my own directory so my files don't get mixed in with things generated by the system.

To put stuff there (in bash):

```
BACKUP="/var/log/maint/backup"
echo "my message" >> "${BACKUP}"
```

The `>>` causes the messages to be appended to the file instead of overwriting it each time.

If my script has a lot of output, I use a script or function for output so everything gets done the same. Below is my current (overkill version): (the VERBOSE stuff is there for when I'm running the script from a terminal and want to see what's going on for debugging purposes.)

```
#!/bin/bash
## backup_logger
## backup system logging module
## Copyleft 01/20/2013 JPmicrosystems
## Usage is ${SCRIPT_NAME} [-v] [<caller> <log message text>]
## If present, -v says log to console as well as to the log file
## <caller> is the name of the calling script
## If <caller> <log message text> is not present, write a blank line to the log

## Must be placed in path, like ~/bin
## If log is owned by root or another user, then this must run as root ...
## If not, it just aborts

##source "/home/bigbird/bin/bash_trace"  ## debug
SCRIPT_NAME="$(basename $0)"
USAGE="Usage is ${SCRIPT_NAME} [-v] [<caller> <log message text>]"
SYSLOGDIR='/var/log/maint'
SYSLOGFILE="${SYSLOGDIR}/backup.log"

LOGGING=1
VERBOSE=0
if [ "${1}" == "-v" ]
then
  VERBOSE=1
  shift
fi

##LOGGING=0  ## debug
##VERBOSE=1  ## debug

## Only zero or two parameters allowed - <caller> <log message text>
RC=0
if [ "$#" -eq 1 ] || [ "$#" -gt 2 ]
then
  echo "${USAGE}"
  RC=1
else
  if [ ! -w "${SYSLOGFILE}" ]
  then
    touch "${SYSLOGFILE}"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
      echo -e "$(date) ${1} ${2}"
      echo "${SCRIPT_NAME} Can't write to log file [${SYSLOGFILE}]"
      RC=1
      exit ${RC}
    fi
  fi

  if [ -n "${1}" ]
  then
    (( LOGGING )) && echo -e "$(date) ${1} ${2}"  >> "${SYSLOGFILE}"
    (( VERBOSE )) && echo -e "$(date) ${1} ${2}"
  else
    (( LOGGING )) && echo "" >> "${SYSLOGFILE}"
    (( VERBOSE )) && echo ""
  fi
fi

exit $RC
```

Edit: Simplistic `at` example which writes to a user file

Haven't used this in forever, so I figured it out with a couple of simple scripts.

The first script just schedules the event using `at`. The command itself could just be typed into a terminal, but I'm lazy - especially when I have to do it multiple times while testing it without fooling with command history.

```
#!/bin/bash
## mytest_at_run
## Schedule a script to run in the immediate future
echo "/home/bigbird/bin/mytest_at_script" | at 00:56
```

The second script is the one which is scheduled to run

```
#!/bin/bash
## mytest_at_script
## The script to be run later
echo "$(date) - is when this ran" >> /home/bigbird/log/at.log
```

I created both scripts in a text editor, saved them, and then made them each executable using `chmod 700 script-file-name`. I put them both in my `$HOME/bin` directory for convenience, but they could be anywhere my user has full access. I use `700` for any script that's just for testing, but on a single user system, it could just as well be `755`.

I already have a directory called `/home/bigbird/log` to save the output from  `mytest_at_script`. This can also be anywhere your user has full access. Just make sure it exists before the script runs or have the script create it.

To run it, I just made sure the time for the `at` command in `mytest_at_run` was a little bit in the future and then ran it from a terminal. I then waited until it ran and examined the contents of `$HOME/log/at.log`.

```
bigbird@sananda:~/bin$ cat ~/log/at.log
Fri Sep 14 00:52:18 EDT 2018 - is when this ran
Fri Sep 14 00:56:00 EDT 2018 - is when this ran
bigbird@sananda:~/bin$
```

A few notes:

Even though I'm running `at` from my user, it doesn't know my environment such as my `PATH` and my home directory, so I don't assume that. I use full paths like I would for any `cron` job. And if I ever want to make it a `cron` job, I won't have to change anything just to make it run.

I used `>>` in `mytest_at_script` to append output to the log file instead of `>` which would have replaced it on every run. Use whichever one suits your application best.

Comment: can you provide me any example to write output to log file using AT command, I'm trying in following way but no result,                                     at now + 1 min
at> echo ""hello" >> /home/camsarch/cams_scripts/texsttest.txt
at> <EOT>

Comment: @PavanKumarVarma - added a simplistic (tested) example using `at` to write to a file. Looks like you got the calling sequence backwards in your example. I'm not very good at telling `at` when to run the job, so I just hard-coded a time in the very near future.